# Updating DNS after changing Static IP

Tags: domain-name-system, static-ip

I have a server that has multiple NICs, each with their own static IP, that I will periodically enable or disable to connect the server to different subsets. Once changed to another subnet, my DNS records still point to the old IP address, so my clients cannot connect to the server.

Is there a way to update the DNS entry from this server so I don't have to log into my DNS server? I tried ipconfig /registerdns but this did not do the trick...

Any help would be appreciated.

TE

Comment: Did you try ipconfig /flushdns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you desire your A-Record to be a dynamically update record vs a static record make sure you tick

```
allow authenticated users to update DNS records with the same owner name
```

[image]

After than you should be able to use

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Comment: Thank you Xiu. I believe this will help and will test next time I change the server's IP.

I also found I had an error when I was using /Registerdns that the RPC server could not be found. this was due to the DHCP client not running.